# GWT 2.6: Setting interface type instance variable from anonymous inner class

Tags: class, gwt, event-handling, outer-join

I'm working on a GWT 2.6 application with a PresenterClass that drives a view that contains a FlexTable. I've connected drag-drop event handlers in the presenter to the FlexTable. Cells can either be vacant or contain an entry. When a drag operation begins, I determine which type of cell is being dragged, and from within the DragStartHandler I set the draggable variable in the outer class to the type that is being dragged. But when the DragOverHandler is called, the draggable instance field in the outer class is null.

What am I not seeing or understanding? I thought anonymous inner classes had access to outer class fields.

```
public class PresenterClass {
  private class CellId {
    int row;
    int column;
  }
  private interface Draggable {
    void beginDrag(CellId cellId);
    void canDrop(CellId cellId);
    void drop(CellId cellId);
  }
  private class VacantSelectedCells implements Draggable {
    .
    .
    .
  }
  private final VacantSelectedCells selectedCells = new SelectedCells();
  private class DraggableEntry implements Draggable {
    .
    . 
    .
  }
  private Draggable draggable;
  private final DragStartHandler dragStartHandler = new DragStartHandler() {
    @override
    public void onDragStart(DragStartEvent event) {
      // Determine what is being dragged
      if (selected cells)
        draggable = selectedCells;
      else
        draggable = new DraggableEntry();
  }
  private final DragOverHandler dragOverHandler = new DragOverHandler() {
    @override
    public void onDragOver(DragOverEvent event) {
      // find cellId for event
      if (draggable.canDrop(cellId))
        doSomething();
    }
  }
```

Comment: They do, but those fields are still permitted to be null. Are you *certain* that `onDragStart` is called first *and* that `selectedCells` is not null?

Comment: Yes, I'm certain selectedCells has been initialized and that onDragStart is called first.

Comment: If thats the case, then the field has been written (and should not be null). If *thats* the case, then the field will not be *read* as null ;). The code compiles, so clearly your field access is legal - something is wrong with your logic. Perhaps you are making two instances of PresenterClass and one has non-null fields, but the other is still null?

Comment: I finally figured out the problem. GWT was sending a DragEnterEvent after DragStartEvent and before DragOverEvent. For some reason, the event data was not what I put there (maybe due to event being triggered by window change when breakpoint hit?) so my handler was setting the field to null.